# Kitchen export problem: empty filter true/false tags

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I work with Pentaho Data Integration 6.1.0.1-196. I run my.bat in which there is an export of the job:
`call kitchen.bat /rep:"%REP_NAME%"  /job:"%2" /dir:"%1" /user:%USER_NAME% /pass:%PASSWORD% /export:"%JOB_FILE%"`
So I get xml file of my job in which there is such a problem:

```
    <type>JavaFilter</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
         <partitioning>
           <method>none</method>
           <schema_name/>
           </partitioning>
<send_true_to/>
<send_false_to/>
```

The problem is that tags "send_true_to/" and "send_false_to/" are empty!
And when I run this jobFile via .bat Javafilter doesn`t work properly.

At the same time this job works ideal in spoon interface.
And if I export this job via spoon interfase it looks correct:

```
    <type>JavaFilter</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
         <partitioning>
           <method>none</method>
           <schema_name/>
           </partitioning>
<send_true_to>Write to log 2</send_true_to>
<send_false_to>Write to log 3</send_false_to>
```

I`ve tried other types of Filter? run .bat as administrator - result is the same.

Please, help me export the job by means of .bat files correctly.
In what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the version of PDI you are using:

https://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-15133 - KTR with Filter Rows step does not save TRUE/FALSE settings when exported to XML from repository

You'll need to either upgrade to 7.0+ or downgrade to 6.0.1.0.
According to the Jira ticket it started in 6.0.1.2.

A workaround would be to install a copy of 6.0.1.0 specifically for the export batch. That should minimize the risk of incompatible stuff being exported and let you keep the existing version for running the jobs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Cyrus